# Response.redirect is not redirecting in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to certain website using c#. I have written the code like:

HTML:

```
 <button id="Buy" class="k-button">Button</button>
```

Script:

```
    $("#Buy").live('click', function () {
        $.ajax({                      
        url: "/Home/Redirect",
        data: JSON.stringify
        ({

        }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",                       
        success: function (str) {
        },
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
      });
```

c#:

```
   public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");          
        return Json("suc",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do a redirect on an ajax post, that will give you a 302 error. What you should be doing is to return the url from you controller method

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    return Json(the_url);
}
```

and then redirect from your client-code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    // your config goes here
    success: function(result) {
        window.location.replace(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because jQuery is picking up the redirect instruction and doing nothing with it. Bear in mind that redirects are handled by the browser, not the server.

Try adding a `complete` callback to your AJAX call to handle the redirect instruction (e.g. after your `success` callback):

```
complete: function(resp) {
    if (resp.code == 302) {
        top.location.href = resp.getResponseHeader('Location');
    }
}
```

This should handle the 302 that the method returns and perform the redirect. Alternatively, return the URL in the JSON as von v suggests.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller,

If you want to redirect a another website, simply we can use like,

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
        //return View();
        return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```